# Text staring with % is not decoded in java UTF8

Tags: javascript, java

Text staring with % is not decoded in java UTF8. But if % is entered following characters UTF8 decodes it correctly. I entered "%kj" in the form field

```js
param.message=encodeURIComponent(message);
```

```
String message = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("message"), "UTF-8");
```

Getting this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "kj"

Comment: according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html), `The character "%" is allowed but is interpreted as the start of a special escaped sequence.`  "%kj" is not a valid escaped sequence.

Comment: Possible duplicate [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067673/urldecoder-illegal-hex-characters-in-escape-pattern-for-input-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067673/urldecoder-illegal-hex-characters-in-escape-pattern-for-input-string)

Comment: Java should be getting `%25kj` rather than `%kj` though, where `%25` is the URL encoding for the `%` character. It's possible that you are trying to URLDecode a message that's already been decoded.

Comment: "Java" probably is getting it.  but it's impossible to tell without more code if the string has already been decoded somewhere else.  (oops!  just saw your edit update.  I agree)

Comment: String is not decoded yet. We are trying to decode it by getting that parameter through request. We tried using  MimeUtility.encodeText(body,"UTF-8","BASE64") and it worked but dont know whether using this is correct or not.